# Design & Logo ideas?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

We've got a while, but no harm in starting to brainstorm now.  Besides, I'm part web designer and I like thinking about these things, even if I don't have a lot of time to contribute in that regard right now.

Also, does anybody know: is there open licensing on the Android logo, or are there copyright issues involved?

Comment: I love the current logo, maybe we should just stick to it.

Comment: @CustomiZer - this was posted back in the beta days, before there was a logo.  I like the current logo, too :)

Comment: Ah, I must have missed the date, my bad. But then why does old topics pop up on my sidebar list ? Isn't that something that must be looked into ?

Comment: Depends. I think the sidebar links are based on cross-links ("Linked") and similar topics ("Related"). Date probably isn't a factor.

Answer (score 10):

According to http://www.android.com/branding.html

> 01/ Android Robot Can be **used, reproduced, and modified freely in marketing communications.** Our standard color value for print is PMS 376C. Our online hex color is **#A4C639**.
>   When using the Android Robot or any modification of it, proper attribution is required under the terms of the Creative Commons Attribution license. For more details on proper attribution, please see [this page](http://code.google.com/policies.html#attribution)
>
> Andoird Typeface/Logo may not be used.

Given that, I think if we maybe have a nice redux of the android style, like how Area51 is done, so it's not so similar to every other droid forum out there, but has it's own flair, that'd be nice.

With an emphasis on robots, so binary, and such. Maybe.

Answer (score 4):

As long as it shows how much we <3 Android!
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Does it look weird to have a pull-able Notification Bar in a website?

Comment: We already have a notification bar appear at the top for new badges, privileges, etc. Adding a fake signal and battery meter to the right end, and maybe an Android icon to left would definitely theme it!

Comment: @GAThrawn: yes we have a notification bar, but it cannot be pulled like Android's notification bar

Comment: A drag-able nav bar is a great idea...

Answer (score 2):

We should definitely make the fav icon the normal robot

Answer (score 2):

A community made font typeface is listed at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=3771562#post3771562

I suggest someone with some creative skills try merging this with the Android logo somehow.