# Right at the end of the standard beta period, how are we doing?

Tags: discussion, beta, statistics

Following on from [Android.SE is on a good track, but we need to work to ensure it survives the beta](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114/android-se-is-on-a-good-track-but-we-need-to-work-to-ensure-it-survives-the-beta), we are now right on **Day 90** of our beta. This is the traditional end of beta day on StackExchange, and there's no sign of us launching yet.

I realize that there is no actual absolute pass/fail happening on the 90th day, this entry from the StackExchange blog covers that [When will my site graduate](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/), but we have reached a good milestone to look at ourselves and think what we need to do to make sure that we do graduate.

## How are we doing?

According to our [page on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18238/android-enthusiasts), we're sitting at Good or Excellent on all stats:

[image]

## What can we do to help?

A lot of this is going to be hard to improve on without attracting a lot more, quality, members to the site. This is where a bit of marketing and self-promotion could go a long way. We need people to ask good questions, and we need people to give good answers (that will be accepted by the questioner).

One easy way to help that anyone can do is to vote. We need more high-rep users to help moderate the site. Vote on good quality, well written, interesting questions, and vote on good-quality, helpful answers. See [What does voting mean and why is it important?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180/what-does-voting-mean-and-why-is-it-important) If you need any further incentive, there are badges available for the first time you use all of your 30 daily votes up, and one for when you've voted 300 times.

## What else should we be doing?

There are [7 essential questions that every beta site should be asking](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/). have we asked all of them? Have we answered all of them in any satisfactory way?

Some of them have been pretty thoroughly thrashed out in various ways, some of them I don't think we've even touched on:

1. Are questions about [subject] on or off topic?

   - Ok, a variety of meta posts go through various aspects of on/off topic, I think we're ok here.
2. What should our FAQ contain?

   - Other than discussion of a [Getting Started Guide](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162/getting-started-guide) I don't think we've really been into this?
3. How should we tag questions about {subject}?

   - Again tagging's been a frequent topic on meta, I think we're covered here.
4. What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

   - This question needs revisiting just to make sure the answers are up to date and we're all happy with them [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)
5. What should our logo and site design look like?

   - We really need to get some ideas together for this, the previous question asked in September has been pretty much ignored since then [Design & Logo ideas?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/design-logo-ideas) and there are no actual logo ideas at all in there. We must have an artist or two in our community?
6. Who should the moderators be?

   - This [has been discussed](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85/moderator-nominations), and we're currently waiting on the SE team to launch a new web-app for voting in moderators, nothing we can do here right now, we have our [Moderators Pro Tempore](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161/moderator-pro-tem-announcement), and I've got no problem with the work they're doing.
7. How do we promote our site?

   - See that "Help us grow this site" box on the right hand side of the main page? Click it and use it! When you're on another Android site where someone has a problem, and you know the answer is already here, point them to the answer here. Every now and then when you're looking at a "hot" question you get asked if you want to share a link to that question elsewhere, why not do that!

Comment: @GAThrawn we don't have to worry about design/logo, Jin will make us one when it's closer to release time.

Comment: @Bryan True, but the other sites have come up with ideas in advance to give to Jin. They had long threads with logo ideas being voted up and down and improved on, and generally when the site launched Jin's logo was based on one of the logo ideas the community came up with. Don't we want to feed Jin some initial ideas?

Comment: You have an unusually large amount of traffic - any idea where is it coming from?

Comment: @kyle: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/211/where-does-the-incoming-traffic-come-from

Comment: SO questions linking to here and some lucky hits with Google. From there I expect users to have a look around the site before leaving, causing more visits

Comment: We need some more 2,000+ rep users.

Comment: We've exited beta. Any reason to keep this question around?